# Tensorboard: Trying to log RGB image. TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tensorboard

I am trying to log an RGB image to Tensorboard. I made sure that my image is a numpy array with the shape (206,127,3). The values inside are numpy.uint8 with a range from 0-255.

When I do:

`writer.add_image("Example Image", img, epoch)`

I get the error:

`TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 206), |u1`

The error seems to come from the PIL module which is used internally by tensorboard. However, I am able to save this image manually using PIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer in the *[tensorboardX documentation](https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#add-image)*:

A shape of (3, H, W) is expected instead of my shape of (H, W, 3).